# ABC analysis with case statement with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, case

Hey I am trying to make an ABC analysis within a my table in a separate column using one variable but my code fails. How can I fix the code to make it work?
Here is my table:

```
declare @t  table (id int, years int)
insert into @t values 
(1, 22),
(2, 45),
(3, 87)
```

and here is my code which fails:

```
declare @age int
set @age = years 

select *,
case
    when @age < 25 then 'a'
    when @age < 50 then 'b'
    else 'c'
end as abc
from @t
```

Thank you!

Comment: This comes up on google for ABC Analysis, but is not relevant to the topic. It would be better to rewrite the title with the error being thrown. People with the same problem can not find this question either, so it is helping no one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set @age = years` is invalid - just remove `@age` and replace with `years` in your query:

```
declare @t  table (id int, years int)
insert into @t values 
(1, 22),
(2, 45),
(3, 87)    

select *,
case
    when years < 25 then 'a'
    when years < 50 then 'b'
    else 'c'
end as abc
from @t
```

More explanation: You can set a variable to a column with select: `set @age = (SELECT years FROM @t)` but this too would fail because a variable can only hold a single value.

So to actually take that approach, you would have to set the variable to a single value and loop through all values:

```
WHILE (condition)
BEGIN
SET @age = (SELECT MAX(years) FROM @t) --something limiting to one value
Query here...
END
```

Looping is generally slow and it's better to avoid it.  In some cases it is necessary of course, but fortunately you can just reference `years` in your case.

**Edit:** If you absolutely had to use a variable `@age` for an exercise or something:

```
DECLARE @id int = 1
DECLARE @Age int

WHILE (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @t) < @id
BEGIN
SET @Age = (SELECT years FROM @t WHERE id = @id)
select *,
       case when @age < 25 then 'a'
            when @age < 50 then 'b'
            else 'c'
       end as abc
from @t

SET @id = @id + 1
END
```

Note: the `SELECT` here doesn't make much sense in the context of a loop, but just for example

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to solve it with a variable that you declare? Oh I see you already answered it!

Comment: @not_ur_avg_cookie Added more example to that loop, but definitely avoid it in this case unless you are just practicing loops :)